# Angular set object to localStorage, problem with amount property

Tags: javascript, angular

I need some help to store products objects to localStorage, im working with Angular and i need to show the amount of the products selected in the template (with the suma: '+' and resta: '-' functions) , and store the object in the localStorage, the problem is that every time i call suma() and resta() functions, the value of product.amount is changing, and that makes a problem to save that object to the localStorage. I can't figure out how to solve this in Angular, the amount property belongs to each product and i can't define as a global value (that makes every product have the same amount). I would like to delete the amount property of the objects, but i need to show that value in the template. Thanks in advance.

```js
let product = {"name":"Almendras", "amount":4};

suma(product) {
    product.amount++;  
    localStorage.setItem(product.name, product.amount);
    console.log(product.name, product.amount);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(product));
}

resta(product) {
    product.amount > 0 ? product.amount-- : 0;
    localStorage.setItem(product.name, product.amount);
    product.amount == 0 ? localStorage.removeItem(product.name) : 0; 
    console.log(product.name, product.amount);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(product));
  }
```

```html
<button (click)="suma(product)"> + </button>
<button (click)="resta(product)"> - </button>
<span>{{product.amount}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're complaining that your product amount is changing when you click Suma, or Resta, but i can see in your code that you are specifically changing these values.

`product.amount++;`   First line of the suma() you are incrementing the amount.

### Edit - additional note

In your template reference the value from localstorage, and not the value of the amount. This will keep your template and local storage in sync. you will need to look up how to do this though sorry

Comment: Exactly, cause i need to show it in the template, im looking for a better way to do this

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: dont forget to upvote as correct answer, if it fits. I will upvote your question when i get more votes back :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an object that has the name as key to store each products amount.

```
let products = {};

suma(product) {
    if (!products[product.name]) {
      products[product.name] = 1;
    } else {
      products[product.name]++;
    }
    localStorage.setItem(product.name, product.amount);
    console.log(product.name, product.amount);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(product));
}

resta(product) {
    if (products[product.name]) {
      products[product.name]--;
      if (products[product.name] <= 0) {
        delete products[product.name];
      }
    }
    localStorage.setItem(product.name, product.amount);
    product.amount == 0 ? localStorage.removeItem(product.name) : 0; 
    console.log(product.name, product.amount);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(product));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer